# input box must resize when div get's smaller

Tags: html, css

My problem is the following:

I have a contact form with multiple input fields. The input fields are on a normal page round about half of the div that they are in. Now when observing my webpage through an browser the problem occurs. The page itself can get smaller than the input fields.

What I would like is the following:

That it resizes to fit in the div instead of overlapping/overflowing outside of the div.

I've tried searching it here on SOF and on google but either I'm searching for the wrong thing or I just can't find it.

HTML:

```
<div id="contact-formulier">
    <form method="post" action="contact.php">
        <label>Naam*</label>
        <input name="naam" placeholder="Graham Neal" required>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input, textarea {
   width:439px;
   height:27px;
   background:#efefef;
   border:1px solid #dedede;
   padding:10px;
   margin-top:3px;
   font-size:0.9em;
   color:#3a3a3a;
   -moz-border-radius:5px;
   -webkit-border-radius:5px;
   border-radius:5px;
}

textarea {
   height:213px;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
   border:1px solid #97d6eb;
}
```

Comment: can you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnnxsrwj/

Comment: what is the problem? what width is the div?

Comment: just like in js fiddle when you make the result screen smaller I want the fields to resize smaller.

Comment: best to use percentages then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the form width to 100% then the input and textarea width to around 90%. I hope this is the result you are seeking for. Just like that:

```
form {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
/* Style the text boxes */
input, textarea {
    width:90%;
    height:27px;
    background:#efefef;
    border:1px solid #dedede;
    padding:10px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies. What i've done is the following. Set the width of the form to 100% and the input, textarea width to 100% and max width to 439px. This way it doesn't get any bigger than I want to be but it does resize.

Comment: Perfect! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

With the width fixed as you put in the css, it's not going to happen.

You could use percentage to obtain this but they don't work perfectly every time in my experience, especially if you do something a little more complex than the simple exercise of your fiddle or if you embed the example into something else.

Best way is using jquery to force the width:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('input').width( $('#contact-formulier').width() - 22);
    });
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnnxsrwj/2/